# Issue on Filtering pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-loc

I am trying to filter this dataset with multiple conditions using `loc`

The data is coming from an Excel file that I imported using

```
df = pd.read_csv()
```

Here is sample structure from the `df` using `df.head()` :

```
df.head()
```

need to filter on the following (columns) criteria: `State-Gov, Bachelors, Never-Married, Adm-Clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, United States, <=50k`

my code currently

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("adult_census_data.csv")

df.head()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIy18.png

```
print(df.loc[df["Sector"].str.strip() == "State-gov"])

df.loc[(df['Sector']=='State-gov') & (df['Education']=='Bachelors') & (df['Married']=='Never-married') & (df['Job']=='Adm-clerical') & (df['Family']=='Not-in-family') & (df['Race']=='White') & (df['Gender']=='Male') & (df['Location']=='United-States') & (df['Income']=='<=50k'), ['Sector', 'Education', 'Married', 'Job', 'Family', 'Race', 'Gender', 'Location', 'Income']]
```

I keep getting `KeyError 'Sector'`

I thought the

```
print(df.loc[df["Sector"].str.strip() == "State-gov"])
```

would remove the blank spaces and clean the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is df['Sector'] is an array which u cannot compare to string "State-gov".
rather you can use for loop through 'Sector' and and get index when the element in array is same as "State-gov".

Comment: hi, thank you for your help - im still new at code - would you be able to show me the right code so i can compare to what i have?